# Spring + Hibernatate 4 + Junit 4 Impossible to get an autoWired session open

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit4

I'm having really trouble with my configuration i think. Here's the problem. Ican open the the session like that :

```
    @Test
    public void testSessionFactory()
    {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
            .addClass(com.mcfly.songme.pojo.Sysparameters.class)
            .configure();
            ServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration
                    .getProperties());

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
                    .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistryBuilder.buildServiceRegistry());
            System.out.println("test");
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            System.out.println("Test connection with the database created successfuly.");
        }catch (Throwable ex) { 
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

But if i do that the session is never openned :

```
    @Test
public void testFindAll() 
{
    try {
        List<Sysparameters> sys = null;
        System.out.println("test");
        SysparametersDAO sysDao = new SysparametersDAO();
        System.out.println("test");
        sys = sysDao.findAll();
        System.out.println(sys.size());
    } catch (Throwable ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

My configuration.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mcfly.songme.pojo" />


    <!-- JDBC data source -->
<!--      <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdb.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/songme"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="10"/> 
        <property name="minIdle" value="5"/> 
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- hibernate session factory  -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mcfly.songme.pojo"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:com/mcfly/songme/pojo/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean> 

    <!-- Hibernate transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!--     Activates annotation based transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


</beans>
```

My dao file :

```
package com.mcfly.songme.pojo;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Component
public class SysparametersDAO 
{
    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();


    @Transactional
    public List<Sysparameters> findAll() 
    {
        try {
            if(getSessionFactory()==null) {
                System.out.println("NULL SESSION FACTORY");
            }
            session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Sysparameters> sys = (List<Sysparameters>) session.createQuery("from sysparameters").list();
        return sys;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

My entity file :

```
package com.mcfly.songme.pojo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

// Generated 8 oct. 2013 16:31:22 by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

/**
 * Sysparameters generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "sysparameters")
public class Sysparameters implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    public Sysparameters() {
    }

    public Sysparameters(String name, String value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

My test file configuration :

```
package com.mcfly.songme.pojo.test;

@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/files-servlet.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SysparameterPOJOTest 
{
```

I really can't understand what i am doing wrong. Thx for help if you got an idea.

---

Still having a session factory null

```
oct. 09, 2013 11:38:06 AM org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@102674b7] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mcfly.songme.pojo.test.SysparameterPOJOTest.testFindAll_(SysparameterPOJOTest.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
```

with that code like you said i tryed to get the session out of the object

```
    @Test
    public void testFindAll_() 
    {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            Sysparameters sys = null;
            SysparametersDAO sysDAO = new SysparametersDAO();
            session = sysDAO.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
//          sys = new SysparametersHome().findById(1);
        } catch (Throwable ex) { 
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        } finally {
            Assert.assertNotNull(session);
        }
    }
```

So my session factory seems to be still null :/

Comment: I'm having this Exception :

   

     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sysparametersDAO' defined in file [C:\Workspace\webTest\songMe\build\classes\com\mcfly\songme\pojo\SysparametersDAO.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.mcfly.songme.pojo.SysparametersDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You can edit your question to add additional information. Don't put that in comments. Also, is `files-servlet.xml` the same file as your configuration.xml you've posted above?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is this

```
@Autowired(required=true)
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

Spring autowiring happens in two steps: first your bean is instantiated (calling default constructor in this case) and then the fields are set using reflection. In the case above, when the object is created, fields are also initialized, by default to `null`. So when

```
private Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

tries to get a `Session` it calls `getCurrentSession()` on a `null` reference.

You shouldn't be getting the `Session` object at the instance level. You should be getting it inside each individual method call.